# How to find the first character of a string and replace all findings of it in the same string in Python?

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to create a method that brings in a string, looks for the first letter of the string and then replaces all occurrences of that letter with another character.

It obviously does not work to use s[letter] to the new character, since letter in this case is not an index. But what solution should be used instead?

```
def fix_start(s):

    letterToReplace = s[0]

    for letter in s:
        if letter is letterToReplace:
            s[letter] = '*'

    return s
```

Comment: Simply `s.replace(s[0], '*')`

Comment: Note that you can't modify a string in python, therefore the resulting string will not be the *same* string. Also therefore your solution will not work since `s[letter] = '*'` would mean modifying the string.

Answer (score 0):

Always keep the manual at hand. The `str` type has a method which is even called [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace).

> **str.replace(old, new[, count])**
>
> Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument count is given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.

So, you can just do

```
def fix_start(s):
  return s.replace(s[0], '*')
```

Note that if you have a situation where you cannot just do `str.replace` (e.g. you have a *list* of strings, not string of characters) the `enumerate` function is handy. It will give you the element *and its index*:

```
def fix_start(sl):
  elementToReplace = sl[0]
  for idx, elem in enumerate(sl):
    if elem == elementToReplace:
      sl[idx] = '*'
  return sl
```

---

On a side node, do not test `letter is letterToReplace` in such cases. The `is` operator tests for *identity*, not equality. Identity means its the same object (same memory address, for example), whereas equality means it has the same meaning (represents the letter `A`, for example).

For basic primitive types (chars, small ints, etc.), python keeps only one object around. For example, `int(1) == int(1)` and `int(1) is int(1)` are equivalent. However, `foo = int(123123); (foo == 123123, foo is 123123)` will fail the `is` test.

Comment: `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment`

Comment: @vaultah As the text says, the second version is not meant for use on `str` but iterables such as `list[str]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/re.html) library:

```
import re

def fix_start(s):
    return re.sub(s[0], "*", s)

print(fix_start("string"))
```

Output:

```
*tring
```

another way is this:

```
def fix_start(s):
    return "".join(map(lambda x: '*' if x is s[0] else x, s))
```

Comment: That is true @SergeBallesta, can't hurt to show the OP another way of doing it, even if it's a bit more complicated.